# Array assignment without for loop

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I meet a problem when assign value to numpy structure. For example, assume I have a numpy array `Src(N*K)`, and an index array `Index(N*1)` whose values are between 0~K-1. My task is to assign the `Src` value to array `Target(N*1)` according to index.

A naive way is using for loop as:

```
for i in xrange(Index.shape[0]):
    Target[i,:] = Src[i,Index[i]]
```

However, I believe there should be other elegant way implementing this task without for loop. So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> Target = np.zeros((4, 4))
>>> Src = np.ones((4, 4))
>>> Index = np.array([1, 2])
>>> Target[i, :] = Src[i, Index, None]
>>> Target
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```